# Crossrider returning zip instead of .crx when installing the extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crossrider

I am trying to install the extension in Chrome and when I click on install then zip file is downloaded not the .crx. How do I install zip file as a chrome extension ?
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Due to recent changes in Chrome's [policy for installing extension **ONLY** from the Chrome Store](http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/27/chrome-for-windows-will-now-only-install-extensions-from-googles-web-store/), it's no longer possible to install an extension using a CRX file. However, you can locally install an extension in Developer mode which requires the extension to be unpacked in a folder.

To make this easier for developers, the Crossrider platform downloads the Chrome installer as a ZIP (not CRX) so that you can easily and intuitively unzip it ready for loading. Once unzipped, simply navigate to the Chrome's **Extension** page (*chrome://extensions/*), make sure that **Developer mode** is selected, and load the extension by clicking **Load unpacked extension**.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]